# How to setup where jTextField clips overlong text?

Tags: java, swing

I've got a `jTextField` with a fixed size (for specific display requirements), but it is filled with variable length text.  Rarely the text can be longer than the box allows (for specific type sizes).  When that happens, the text field clips the beginning of the displayed text, just showing the last part that will fit.  I would rather clip the end and display the beginning portion.

I'd like to do this in the `jTextField` rather than trying to calculate it myself as we do support variable size type as well as different fonts which makes calculating clipping ourselves simply based on length a hassle.

The field is display only (editable false).  I'd thought that setting `scrollOffset` value would do this, but it seems to have no effect.  I also experimented with `selectionStart` values as I **can** shift the clipping area by mouse selecting the contained text.  However, that also did not seem to do anything when done programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the caret position of the `jTextField`:

```
jTextField.setCaretPosition(0);
```

However, points to note:

**1)** This must be done *after* the text has been populated

**2)** (This probably won't affect you) If the user clicks on the text field, it will automatically move the position to the end, i.e. the way you don't want.